# Binaryton -- Two Instances of One Object

Tags: design-patterns

In design patterns we have the Singleton, which ensures there is only one instance of a class.

I love design patterns so I was wondering, what if we only wanted two instances of that class? So ignoring the real world application this may or may not have; how would you ensure there are only two instances of one class?

I have an idea myself how to do it, but I am curious about what other people come up with and I do not want to bias anyone.

Explain your answer. Showing code is also welcomed.

Again the question is: **How would you ensure there are only two instances of one class?**

EDIT: This is just for fun, there isn't, necessarily, a real world application for this fake pattern. I just want to see what approach we can all come up with as a group.

Comment: I don't think you can ignore whether there is a real life application of this "pattern". How would you access these objects? How would you decide which object to return?

Comment: You would provide the user of your class with the option of choosing which object to call. Ideally, the class would handle itself and provide the user with an object out of the two -- that's just my vision. This is all theoretical, I am not saying go out there and use this in your project.

Comment: There's a lot of problems with this question. For instance, how would the programmer choose which of the two instance he would use? And why? Answers to those questions would dictate a lot about the solution.

Comment: `Singleton` is a very misused pattern and I can't really see one single use for you `Binaryton` or whatever, but a way to do this is just put other property and methods to get instante number 2...

Comment: this question has less to with pattern and more to algorithm. @FunctionR, i guess the question should read: *what is the optimal algo to make sure a class can be instantiated not more than twice?* do i understand correctly?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Whether the Singleton Pattern is misused or not is irrelevant to this question. The only related aspect is that I want to control how an object is created and how many of it there are. I am keeping the problem to two instances, but it could be n. Again, the real application of this `Binaryton` is not important to me. I am more interested in an intelligent approach to this little problem.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I got a scenario for the question that might help put it in perspective. You have threads, for some odd reason each thread asks for a Singleton object and Binaryton replies by designating one Singleton to a thread. The logic that dictates who gets object 1 or object 2 is hidden from the user of the class.

Answer (score 1):

For an answer, we can reference Effective Java (2nd Edition) Item 3: "Enforce the singleton property with a private constructor or an enum type"

Both approaches would support any fixed number of instances, though an enum seems ideally suited. For example:

```java
public class SimpleLoadBalancer {
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return RANDOM.nextBoolean() ?
                BinaryConnection.CONNECTION_ONE:
                BinaryConnection.CONNECTION_TWO;
    }

    public interface Connection {
        void connect();
    }

    private enum BinaryConnection implements Connection {
        CONNECTION_ONE("connection_string_one"),
        CONNECTION_TWO("connection_string_two");

        private final String connectionString;
        private BinaryConnection(String con) {
            connectionString = con;
        }

        @Override
        public void connect() {
            // some connection logic here
        }
    }
}
```